# Unknown exception or error on Assembly.GetTypes during runtime

Tags: c#

I have following code in project and it works fine on my machine but when I run this on my testing machine it crashes on method plugin.GetTypes(). Assembly is loaded properly though.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var files = di.GetFiles(dllName, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (var file in files) {
        Assembly plugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);
        try
        {
           foreach (Type pluginType in plugin.GetTypes()) {
            // dealing with pluginTypes...
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        } }
```

Problem is that I don't have an option debug code with Visual Studio there. I tried simply

```
try {
    var temp = plugin.GetTypes();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

but it never catches any exception, it always just crash. On that machine I use same full debug folder to run an app.

Comment: Does the Event Viewer on the testing machine reveal any exception information?

Comment: Sounds like a missing DLL. Its worth checking that any references (non default) have been set to CopyLocal.

Comment: You can also try adding an event handler for [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) to try to get the exception information.

Comment: How is it that you can't debug this? Have you tried remote debugging? WinDbg? ProcDump?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that one reference really wasn't set to CopyLocal. Thanks to Hellix 88.